# Magento 2: Invoice PDF update google fonts possible?

Tags: magento2, frontend, magento2.2.4

I want to update Logo in Invoice Pdf.

Also, I am looking for update google fonts.

I am looking for any solution but not getting an exact answer. Should I go through custom module and override pdf module Or is there any solution is available in back-end?

If anyone does it please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow below code ....

***Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php***

Need to override this class into your custom module..

create **di.xml** under ***app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/adminhtml/di.xml***

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />
</config>
```

***[VendorName][ModuleName]\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php***

```
/**
 * Set font as regular
 *
 * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
 * @param  int $size
 * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
 */
protected function _setFontRegular($object, $size = 7)
{
    $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
        $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/LinLibertineFont/LinLibertine_Re-4.4.1.ttf')
    );
    $object->setFont($font, $size);
    return $font;
}

/**
 * Set font as bold
 *
 * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
 * @param  int $size
 * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
 */
protected function _setFontBold($object, $size = 7)
{
    $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
        $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/LinLibertineFont/LinLibertine_Bd-2.8.1.ttf')
    );
    $object->setFont($font, $size);
    return $font;
}

/**
 * Set font as italic
 *
 * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
 * @param  int $size
 * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
 */
protected function _setFontItalic($object, $size = 7)
{
    $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
        $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/LinLibertineFont/LinLibertine_It-2.8.2.ttf')
    );
    $object->setFont($font, $size);
    return $font;
}
 /**
     * Insert logo to pdf page
     *
     * @param \Zend_Pdf_Page &$page
     * @param null $store
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    protected function insertLogo(&$page, $store = null)
    {
        $this->y = $this->y ? $this->y : 815;
        $image = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'sales/identity/logo',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $store
        );
        if ($image) {
            $imagePath = '/sales/store/logo/' . $image;
            if ($this->_mediaDirectory->isFile($imagePath)) {
                $image = \Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($imagePath));
                $top = 830;
                //top border of the page
                $widthLimit = 270;
                //half of the page width
                $heightLimit = 270;
                //assuming the image is not a "skyscraper"
                $width = $image->getPixelWidth();
                $height = $image->getPixelHeight();

                //preserving aspect ratio (proportions)
                $ratio = $width / $height;
                if ($ratio > 1 && $width > $widthLimit) {
                    $width = $widthLimit;
                    $height = $width / $ratio;
                } elseif ($ratio < 1 && $height > $heightLimit) {
                    $height = $heightLimit;
                    $width = $height * $ratio;
                } elseif ($ratio == 1 && $height > $heightLimit) {
                    $height = $heightLimit;
                    $width = $widthLimit;
                }

                $y1 = $top - $height;
                $y2 = $top;
                $x1 = 25;
                $x2 = $x1 + $width;

                //coordinates after transformation are rounded by Zend
                $page->drawImage($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);

                $this->y = $y1 - 10;
            }
        }
    }
```

***Now just customise those function with your requirement.***
***you can use your own font lib.***

Answer (score 0):

Mr R DNATH's answer above worked a treat!

Note when you override invoice.php, by placing your own version in your own Magento module, you'll need the following at the top of the file:

```
namespace <VENDOR>\<MODULE>\Model\Order\Pdf;

use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Collection;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config;
```

Also if you use system fonts, as opposed to fonts inline in your code base, you'll need to change the references to those files too.

i.e.

```
/**
 * Set font as regular
 *
 * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
 * @param  int $size
 * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
 */
protected function _setFontRegular($object, $size = 7)
{
    $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath('/usr/share/fonts/some-font.ttf');
    $object->setFont($font, $size);
    return $font;
}
```